# How would I Prove the algorithm correct using the initialization-maintenance-termination technique?

Tags: c, algorithm, loop-invariant

And what would be the conditions that must be met during execution of the function? (Assertion)

I want to make sure that my assertion would describe what I know is true after running the ith loop.

```
int linearsearch(int arr[], int n, int target) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == target) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is just an iterative linear search function that returns the index of the target if the target is found and -1 otherwise.

Comment: `assert(arr != NULL);` before loop.

Comment: Rarely needed: `assert(n <= SIZE_MAX);`

Comment: You need to assume that `arr` points to at least `n` ints (contained in the same object I suppose). Then you naturally get that `arr!=NULL` and `n<=SIZE_MAX`. If you don't make this assumption, `arr[i]` may cause undefined behavior, invalidating your proof.

Answer (score 2):

Loop invariant for the problem of linear search must make a statement about all array elements that were previously searched, namely, that none of them is equal to `target`:

#### ∀ *j* < *i* : arr<sub>*j*</sub> ≠ target

You need to prove several points about it:

- Show that the invariant holds before entering the loop
- Show that if the invariant holds before an iteration, it also holds upon completion of the iteration
- Show that if the loop ends through return in the middle, the algorithm produces the correct result
- Show that if the loop ends normally, the algorithm also produces the correct result

Comment: I think you must also assume that `arr` points to at least `n` ints.